# How to insert or update an a array in MongoDB with Node.Js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a `products` collection where some products have this structure :

```
{
_id: anID
shops: 
[
  {
    _id : shopId,
    price: productsPrice
  },
  ...
]
}
```

I would like update the price of a given products and shop, but insert this shop with his price if it is not present in the array.

I'm a beginner with MongoDB.Working with Node.Js/express(mongoDB driver) but not using mongoose.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html) - which will either push a new shop object or update existing :

```
var inputObj = { "_id": anShopID, "price": someValue }
db.collection.bulkWrite([{
    updateOne: {
        "filter": { "_id": anID, "shops._id": inputObj._id },
        "update": { $set: { "shops.$.price": inputObj.price } }
    }
}, {
    updateOne: {
        "filter": { "_id": anID, "shops._id": { $ne: inputObj._id } },
        "update": { $push: { "shops": inputObj } }
    }
}])
```